# Why doesn't the Inset item show in Prolog in a plot?

Tags: graphics, wolfram-mathematica

I apologise for the length of this question. My current Mathematica programming project involves replicating the very specific business rules my employing institution has for publication-quality plots of time series. One of these rules is that multipanel graphs have panel titles and subtitles centered near the top of the plot area. This worked fine using `Prolog` and `Inset` until I redid that bit of the function to allow explicit `Prolog` elements to be included as well. Then only the item passed in the `Prolog` option shows, not the panel titles and subtitles. If there is no explicit `Prolog` option, the panel titles and subtitles show up fine.

To explicate a bit further, imagine the function body is all in a big `Module`, including the local variable `pl=OptionValue[Prolog]` and `mp=OptionValue[MultiPanel]`.

A bit further down is this definition (`ppl`, `title` and `subtitle` were also defined as local variables, and `Rfont` and `framecol` are constants defined elsewhere in the package, namely to be `"Arial"` and `"Black"`):

```
ppl=If[mp===False,pl,If[Length[pl]>0,Join[{ 
If[ToString[subtitle] == "None",  Inset[
DisplayForm[GridBox[{{Style[title, 20, FontFamily -> Rfont, framecol]}}]],
    Scaled[{0.5,0.96}],{Center,Top} ], 
Inset[DisplayForm[
GridBox[{{Style[title, 20, FontFamily -> Rfont, framecol]}, 
     {Style[subtitle, 16, FontFamily -> Rfont, framecol]}}, 
     RowSpacings -> 0]],Scaled[{0.5,0.98}],{Center,Top}] ]},pl],
  {If[ToString[subtitle] == "None",  
     Inset[ DisplayForm[
       GridBox[{{Style[title, 20, FontFamily -> Rfont, framecol]}}]],
      Scaled[{0.5,0.96}],{Center,Top} ], 
      Inset[DisplayForm[
        GridBox[{{Style[title, 20, FontFamily -> Rfont, framecol]}, 
                  {Style[subtitle, 16, FontFamily -> Rfont, framecol]}},
        RowSpacings -> 0]],Scaled[{0.5,0.98}],{Center,Top}]] }] ]
```

All fine as far as it goes. The `Inset` is used if the option `MultiPanel` (and thus `mp`) is not `False` and there is no `Prolog` explicitly set. But if a prolog is set, e.g., `Prolog -> {Text["test", Scaled[{0.6`, 0.5`}]]}`, then the `Inset` doesn't show, only the `Text` element.

It isn't a problem with the way I am joining them together. Capturing and printing the value of `ppl` gives:

```
{Inset[{{Style["This is a test", LineColor -> GrayLevel[0], 
FrontFaceColor -> GrayLevel[0],   BackFaceColor -> GrayLevel[0], 
GraphicsColor -> GrayLevel[0], FontFamily -> "Arial", FontSize -> 20, 
FontColor -> GrayLevel[0]]}, 
{Style["Year-ended percentage change", LineColor -> GrayLevel[0], 
FrontFaceColor -> GrayLevel[0], BackFaceColor -> GrayLevel[0], 
GraphicsColor -> GrayLevel[0], FontFamily -> "Arial", FontSize -> 16, 
FontColor -> GrayLevel[0]]}}, 
Scaled[{0.5, 0.98}], {Center, Top}], Text["test", Scaled[{0.6, 0.5}]]}
```

(And yes, those are a bunch of undocumented options which I shall ask about in another question.)

*Does anyone know if there is anything preventing `Prolog` (or `Epilog` for that matter) combining `Inset` elements and other things in the one set of graphics options?*

Comment: Aside: You could simplify your code a bit by ``If[Length[pl] > 0, 
 Join[{"long", "bit of", "code"}, pl], {"long", "bit of", "code"}]`` with 
``Join[{"long", "bit of", "code"}, If[Length[pl] > 0, pl, {}]]``

Comment: So it looks like `ppl` is what you want it to be (other than those unknown options). I can include it as a `Prolog` in a plot and it looks fine. If this is so then I don't think that you've given us the bit of code where the problem is actually occurring.

Comment: @Simon: +1 on the Aside. I had been wrestling with the fact of the `Prolog` problem for so long that I had forgotten that `Join[{a,b},{}]` returns `{a,b}`. I was trying to avoid a `Null` in a list of things to show as the `Prolog`. Duh.

Comment: Actually, since the default value for `Prolog` is `{}`, perhaps one doesn't even need the `If`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I feel a bit stupid now. I worked out the issue. Let me see if I can explain clearly enough.

Suppose you have a custom function (say, `XYZPlot`) that is built on a built-in one (say, `DateListPlot`). Suppose you want to pass some options to `DateListPlot`, as well as handling some options that are specific to `XYZPlot`. Then you probably want to pass any options the user includes explicitly *before* you pass the default options that apply to your custom function. This is a toy example: normally you'd set default `PlotRange` as an option to your custom function with `SetOptions` etc.

```
defaultplotrange = {1,5};
XYZPlot[args___,opts:OptionsPattern[{XYZPlot,DateListPlot}]]:=
  DateListPlot[args,Sequence @@ FilterRules[{opts}, Options[DateListPlot]],
    PlotRange->defaultplotrange]
```

So far so good. But if you want to catch the value of an option and modify it *even if the user provides an explicit value for it when they call the function*, for example to add [ahem] panel titles if some other option is set to `True`, then you can't put that option after the `FilterRules` bit. It has to come before. Otherwise the value of `Prolog` that the user gave will be used, not the one with the bit added. So the right way is to do something like this.

```
defaultplotrange = {1,5};
XYZPlot[args___,opts:OptionsPattern[{XYZPlot,DateListPlot}]]:=
  With[{pl=OptionValue[Prolog],mp=OptionValue[MultiPanel]},
  DateListPlot[args,
  Prolog -> If[mp===False,pl,Join[pl,{Inset[(* something else *)]}]],
  Sequence @@ FilterRules[{opts}, Options[DateListPlot]],
    PlotRange->defaultplotrange]]
```

Sorry to bother you all.

Answer (score 3):

As you have not given a working fragment of code, I'm not sure what's going wrong in it.

How does my simple example not replicate what you're trying?

```
plot = Plot[x^2, {x, -5, 5}, Prolog -> Inset[Style[Text[":) = \[HappySmiley]"], Large]]]
```

[image]

```
pl = Flatten@{Prolog /. AbsoluteOptions[plot, Prolog]}
```

[image]

```
join = Show[{Plot[x^2 + 1, {x, -5, 5}, PlotStyle -> Red], 
             Plot[x^2, {x, -5, 5}, PlotStyle -> Blue]}, 
            Prolog -> Join[{Inset[Graphics@Circle[]]}, If[Length[pl] > 0, pl, {}]]]
```

[image]

Comment: You might be getting the smiley equation because it's part of `plot`, which you are `Show` ing at the same time as your other `Plot` in red. There are too many other things going on in my code to suddenly `Show` an extraneous plot.

Comment: @Verbeia: Good point - but it's not true. I'll edit it to make it clear.