# What do these undocumented Style options in Mathematica do?

Tags: graphics, wolfram-mathematica, text-formatting

As mentioned in an [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6894196/why-doesnt-the-inset-item-show-in-prolog-in-a-plot), I have uncovered some style options that don't appear in the Mathematica documentation.

```
Style["This is a test", LineColor -> GrayLevel[0], 
FrontFaceColor -> GrayLevel[0], BackFaceColor -> GrayLevel[0], 
GraphicsColor -> GrayLevel[0], FontFamily -> "Arial", 
FontSize -> 20, FontColor -> GrayLevel[0]]
```

`LineColor`, `FrontFaceColor`, `BackFaceColor` and `GraphicsColor` aren't documented anywhere,  show up in red when used in the front end, throw an error when used inside a `Graphics` element and generally don't seem to have any function.

What are these options used for or why they turn up in this context?

Comment: Which version of mma are you using? Where did you come across these options?  In my case (mma 8.0.1, OS X) none of them (`LineColor`, `FrontFaceColor`, `BackFaceColor`, `GraphicsColor`) is included in the output of `Options[Style]`.

Comment: Same as you, mma 8.0.1, OS X. Bizarre, aren't they? They turned up in an `InputForm` of something I was debugging (see the earlier embarrassing question). They don't turn up in `Options[Style]` and don't seem to do anything. But there they were in the `Print` of an intermediate result.

Comment: Yes, that is bizarre.  Perhaps legacy debris from an earlier version?

Comment: Nothing comes up in Google, so if so, they were undocumented then.

Comment: I guess you're using Google China then, because I get more than 500 hits for FrontFaceColor. Looks like it is an undocumented option of StyleBox. I know of more undocumented options, and I assume they are undocumented for a reason. I don't think it's advisable to use them customarily.

Comment: @Sjoerd I get many results too, but none of them is a doc, just code (without comments ...)

Comment: <waves hand>These are not the Style options you're looking for.</waves>

Comment: @Brett, Would you kindly explain "These are not the Style options you're looking for"?

Comment: @David The presence of these symbols is merely a leak of a front-end implementation detail into a user-visible structure.  There's no reason for the average person to be interested in them.  (I could probably count the set of people who should care about these options on one hand, and I'm not one of them.)

Comment: @Brett Thanks for the explanation. I am generally oblivious to such stuff (and actually glad I don't have to think about it.)

Comment: @Brett: Your comments are in fact, the answer to the question. Please post them below.

Comment: @Sjoerd, sorry I should have been more specific. There are hits in Google (even Google Australia), but nothing in the form of documentation. But this link suggests that Brett's explanation is the right one, and it's something to do with the form-type layouts one sees in Manipulates: http://www.wolfram.com/products/mathematica/newin6/content/DynamicGraphicalInput/UseFormsDirectlyAsEvaluatableInput.html

Comment: @verbeia Since you're so fond of undocumented options I'll give you a real useful one: Method -> {"ShrinkWrap" -> True} is an undocumented option of Plot or Show. It removes whitespace that MMA adds as a tiny rim to each plot. No *Padding option gets rid of this, but this secret option does the trick.

Comment: Folks, I was wondering if it's worth setting up a community wiki page to collect the undocumented options that we find?

Comment: @Brett I agree with yoda; please post your comment as an answer so that this question will not appear as unanswered.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[per popular demand...]

The presence of these symbols is merely a leak of a front-end implementation detail into a user-visible structure. There's no reason for the average person to be interested in them. (I could probably count the set of people who should care about these options on one hand, and I'm not one of them.)